# Change Name of Variable Based on Arguements Passed In

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a point counter where when a button is clicked the points for one person increases. Then once it hits a certain amount of points then it will say something like game over. This is very easy to do. I can just do something like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="add-p1-point">Give player 1 a point</button>
<button id="add-p2-point">Give player 2 a point</button>
<span id="p1-score">P1 Score:</span>
<span id="p2-score">P2 Score:</span>
```

JS:

```
    const p1PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p1-point');
    const p2PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p2-point');

    let p1Score = 0;
    let p2Score = 0;

    p1PointAdded.addEventListener('click', p1PointWon);
    p2PointAdded.addEventListener('click', p2PointWon);

    function p1PointWon() {
        p1Score++;
        document.getElementById('p1-score').innerText = `P1 Score: ${p1Score}`;
        if (p1Score == 3) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert('Player 1 won');
            }, 1);
        }
    }

    function p2PointWon() {
        p2Score++;
        document.getElementById('p2-score').innerText = `P2 Score: ${p2Score}`;
        if (p2Score == 3) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert('Player 2 won');
            }, 1);
        }
    }
```

However, I was just wondering if there was a way to have one singular function with a parameter of player. Then, if the function was called with an argument of p1 all the variables and other things would have p1 and vice versa.

Example (of course this doesn't work):

```
    const p1PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p1-point');
    const p2PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p2-point');
    const p1Score = document.getElementById('p1-score');
    const p2Score = document.getElementById('p2-score')

    let p1Score = 0;
    let p2Score = 0;

    p1PointAdded.addEventListener('click', pointWon(p1));
    p2PointAdded.addEventListener('click', pointWon(p2));

    function pointWon(player) {
        player + 'Score'++;
        player + 'Score'.innerText = `${player} Score: ${player + 'Score'}`;
        if (player + 'Score' == 3) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert(`Player ${player} won`);
            }, 1);
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to possibly concatenate the parameter and the second word of the variable.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind an object to the function and the function takes `this` as player.

```js
function pointWon() {
    this.score++;
    this.element.innerText = `${this.player} Score: ${this.score}`;
    if (this.score === 3) {
        setTimeout(() => alert(`Player ${this.player} won`), 1);
    }
}

const
    p1PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p1-point'),
    p2PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p2-point'),
    p1 = {
        player: 'P1',
        element: document.getElementById('p1-score'),
        score: 0,
    },
    p2 = {
        player: 'P2',
        element: document.getElementById('p2-score'),
        score: 0,
    };

p1PointAdded.addEventListener('click', pointWon.bind(p1));
p2PointAdded.addEventListener('click', pointWon.bind(p2));
```

```html
<button id="add-p1-point">Give player 1 a point</button>
<button id="add-p2-point">Give player 2 a point</button>
<span id="p1-score">P1 Score: 0</span>
<span id="p2-score">P2 Score: 0</span>
```

Another approach could use a closure over the player and utilize your first intended approach.

```js
function pointWon(player) {
    return function () {
        player.score++;
        player.element.innerText = `${player.player} Score: ${player.score}`;
        if (player.score === 3) {
            setTimeout(() => alert(`Player ${player.player} won`), 1);
        }
    };
}

const
    p1PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p1-point'),
    p2PointAdded = document.getElementById('add-p2-point'),
    p1 = {
        player: 'P1',
        element: document.getElementById('p1-score'),
        score: 0,
    },
    p2 = {
        player: 'P2',
        element: document.getElementById('p2-score'),
        score: 0,
    };

p1PointAdded.addEventListener('click', pointWon(p1));
p2PointAdded.addEventListener('click', pointWon(p2));
```

```html
<button id="add-p1-point">Give player 1 a point</button>
<button id="add-p2-point">Give player 2 a point</button>
<span id="p1-score">P1 Score: 0</span>
<span id="p2-score">P2 Score: 0</span>
```